# scrollTo function within PHP to href attribute with an offset?

Tags: jquery, href, attr, scrollto

So I am amending a theme that uses the scrollTo function, which works fine as it is, but due to me adding a fixed header to the page, when I click on the links it goes to the correct position but my header covers part of the content that is at that position. I want to offset the y scrolling position so that my header is just above the content instead of right over on top of it. The website is http://www.trevrandmarissa.com/.

The PHP file that runs the script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
    // Setup the site navigation
    jQuery('#mainNav').visualNav({
      link              : 'a',
      targetAttr        : 'href',
      inViewClass       : 'inView',
      selectedClass     : 'selected',
      selectedAppliedTo : 'a',
      contentClass      : 'soloSection',
      contentLinks      : 'visualNav',
      bottomMargin      : 200,
      animationTime     : <?php echo $scroll_speed; ?>  
    });

    // Add scrollTo capability to special links and buttons
    jQuery(".scrollToBtn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.scrollTo(jQuery(this).attr("href"),  <?php echo $scroll_speed; ?> )
    });
    });
</script>
```

I want to add say about a 100 pixel offset from the top to push the content down enough so that the header isn't covering the heading of the section and the rest of the content. If you click on the links on the page you'll see how it is being covered.

Thank you!

P.S. The PHP calling the scroll speed is a function built into the theme, right now you can just assume `<?php echo $scroll_speed; ?>` is 1200.

I've tried

```
jQuery(".scrollToBtn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.scrollTo(jQuery(this).attr("href").offset().top-300,  <?php echo     $scroll_speed; ?> );
    });
```

but it won't work.

Comment: what is the `href` in `jQuery(this).attr("href")`? like what is a value?

Comment: the `href` I believe matches what the link is with the ID that the div is given when the PHP generates the page. The link is `#location` in the header, and then it finds the generated link on the page that has `location` as the ID. If I'm understanding it correctly, the PHP generates the pages individually from the database when the page is loaded and then the javascript just listens to the matching ID's.

Answer (score -1):

I did a quickfix for the time being:

1. set useHash to FALSE
2. update the jquery.visualNav.js file by searching for "offset().top" and subtract the height of your fixed header.